# Searching a pandas dataframe for multiple strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with a column 'Names' and I have a separate list of strings which are of the form:

```
info = ['AAA.123+456.789', 'BBB.987+654.321', 'CCC.321-654.987']
```

and so on. I want to search the 'Names' column in df using strings in the list and store the result in a separate dataframe (df2). I used:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['Names'].str.contains('|'.join(info))]
```

however the output for df2 (in the spyder variable explorer) was either an empty dataframe or only one of the results was returned. I'm not sure how I can fix this so any advice would be appreciated - thanks!

**Edit**

| Index | Names | Quantity 1 | Quantity 2 | Quantity 3 | Quantity 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAA | 12.3 | 4.56 | 7.89 | 10.1112 |
| 1 | BBB | 3.21 | 65.4 | 98.7 | 1.21110 |
| 2 | CCC | 456.23 | 1.23 | 10101 | 101.112 |
| 3 | DDD | 6.4 | 3.21 | 0.2029 | 1211.10 |

is a sample of df's contents (it's 6 columns and a very high number of rows)

**Edit 2**

Have relabelled 'list' as 'info' on the suggestion of Serge in comments

Comment: Please show a sample of your dataframe's contents.

Comment: Do not call your list by list. That is reserved to define lists.

Comment: additionally, try to provide a **minmal** reproducible example. Try to create some dummy data that produces the same problem. For example, use less complex string patterns to start with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this. If your df is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Names":['AAA.123+456.789', "BBB.987+654.321", "W1234", "A_aa_1+.", "Z54"], "col1":[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

```
info = ['AAA.123+456.789', 'BBB.987+654.321', 'CCC.321-654.987']
```

and

```
df2 = df[df['Name'].isin(info)]
```

gives:

```
    Names  col1
0  AAA.123+456.789     1
1  BBB.987+654.321     2
```

Comment: Hmmn ok, the weird thing is when I use the above method, I still get an Empty DataFrame with 6 columns as the result for df2? I'm almost certain the strings in 'info' are in the df as I have copied over the corresponding entries in df into info...

Comment: Okay amazing think it works now, thanks so much!